# How to add opacity map to ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js

I've applied ShaderMaterial to a glb model that has opacity map (the model is human body and the opacity map is used to create hair and eyelashes), the reference for the model material was this -

[image]

So as you can see - the material is some sort of glow effect, so i was manage to find [This Example](https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/VwjQBqV) which is pretty much what i need - the problem is that i can't figure out how to apply the models opacity map - if you look closely on the difference between my result (left picture) to the right picture - you'll see that the hair doesn't looks as it should - since the opacity map do not applied... i wonder is the ShaderMaterial is the good for this look or should i use other kind of shader.

[image]

Here is my material code -

```
  let m = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  roughness: 0.25,
  metalness: 0.75,
  opacity: 0.3,

  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    "/maps/opacity.jpg",
    (tex) => {
      tex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      tex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      tex.repeat.set(16, 1);
    }
  ),
  onBeforeCompile: (shader) => {
    
    shader.uniforms.s = uniforms.s;
    shader.uniforms.b = uniforms.b;
    shader.uniforms.p = uniforms.p;

    shader.uniforms.glowColor = uniforms.glowColor;
    shader.vertexShader = document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent;
    shader.fragmentShader = document.getElementById(
      "fragmentShader"
    ).textContent;
    shader.side = THREE.FrontSide;
    shader.transparent = true;
  //  shader.uniforms['alphaMap'].value.needsUpdate = true;

    console.log(shader.vertexShader);
    console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  },
});
```

Shader setting:

```
      <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vPositionNormal;
    void main() 
    {
      vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal ); // 转换到视图空间
      vPositionNormal = normalize(( modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0) ).xyz);
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
  </script>
  <!-- fragment shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
  <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
    uniform vec3 glowColor;
    uniform float b;
    uniform float p;
    uniform float s;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vPositionNormal;
    void main() 
    {
      float a = pow( b + s * abs(dot(vNormal, vPositionNormal)), p );
      gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(vec3(0), glowColor, a), 1. );
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `MeshStandardMaterial`, but then you're overriding all its shader code when you assign new vertex and fragment shaders, making the Standard material useless. You should stick to `ShaderMaterial` like the demo you linked. It would make your code cleaner:

```js
// Get shader code
let vertShader = document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent;
let fragShader = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent;

// Build texture
let alphaTex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("/maps/opacity.jpg");
alphaTex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
alphaTex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
// alphaTex.repeat.set(16, 1); <- repeat won't work in a custom shader

// Build material
let m = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    transparent: true,
    // side: THREE.FrontSide, <- this is already default. Not needed
    uniforms: {
        s: {value: 1},
        b: {value: 2},
        p: {value: 3},
        alphaMap: {value: alphaTex},
        glowColor: {value: new THREE.Color(0x0099ff)},
        // we create a Vec2 to manually handle repeat 
        repeat: {value: new THREE.Vector2(16, 1)} 
    },
    vertexShader: vertShader,
    fragmentShader: fragShader
});
```

This helps build you material in a cleaner way, since you're using its native build method without having to override anything. Then, you can sample the `alphaMap` texture in your fragment shader:

```glsl
uniform float s;
uniform float b;
uniform float p;
uniform vec3 glowColor;
uniform vec2 repeat;
// Declare the alphaMap uniform if we're gonna use it
uniform sampler2D alphaMap;

// Don't forget to declare UV coordinates
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 vPositionNormal;
void main() 
{
  float a = pow( b + s * abs(dot(vNormal, vPositionNormal)), p );

  // Sample map with UV coordinates. Multiply by uniform to get repeat
  float a2 = texture2D(alphaMap, vUv * repeat).r;

  // Combine both alphas
  float opacity = a * a2;

  gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(vec3(0), glowColor, opacity), 1. );
}
```

Also, don't forget to carry over the UVs from your vertex shader:

```glsl
// Don't forget to declare UV coordinates
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 vPositionNormal;
void main() 
{
  // convert uv attribute to vUv varying
  vUv = uv;
  vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal ); // 转换到视图空间
  vPositionNormal = normalize(( modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0) ).xyz);
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

**Update**

The error

> '=' : cannot convert from 'lowp 4-component vector of float' to 'highp float'

means I made a mistake when taking the `texture2D()` sample in the fragment shader. It should have been `texture2D().r` so we only read the red channel to get a `float` instead of cramming all RGBA channels (yielding a `vec4`) into a `float`. See the following snippet for the final result:

```js
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, torusKnot;
init()
        
function init() {
  initBase()
  initObject()
  render()
}

function initBase () {
  container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' )

  // SCENE
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  // CAMERA
  var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight
  var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR)

  camera.position.set(0,0,50)
  camera.lookAt(scene.position)
  // RENDERER
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} )
  renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
  renderer.setClearColor(0x333333)
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement )
  // CONTROLS
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement )
  
  // Resize
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize(w, h);
        camera.aspect = w / h;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}


function initObject () {
  let vertShader = document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent;
let fragShader = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent;
// Build texture
let alphaTex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/floors/FloorsCheckerboard_S_Diffuse.jpg");
alphaTex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
alphaTex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        s: {value: -1},
        b: {value: 1},
        p: {value: 2},
        alphaMap: {value: alphaTex},
        glowColor: {value: new THREE.Color(0x00ffff)},
        // we create a Vec2 to manually handle repeat 
        repeat: {value: new THREE.Vector2(16, 1)} 
    },
    vertexShader: vertShader,
    fragmentShader: fragShader
  })
  var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotBufferGeometry( 10, 3, 100, 32 )
  torusKnot = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, customMaterial )
  scene.add( torusKnot )

}

function render() {
  torusKnot.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <!-- vertext shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 vPositionNormal;
void main() 
{
  // convert uv attribute to vUv varying
  vUv = uv;
  vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal ); // 转换到视图空间
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  vPositionNormal = normalize(( mvPosition ).xyz);
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
  </script>
  <!-- fragment shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
  <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
   uniform float s;
uniform float b;
uniform float p;
uniform vec3 glowColor;
uniform vec2 repeat;
// Declare the alphaMap uniform if we're gonna use it
uniform sampler2D alphaMap;

// Don't forget to declare UV coordinates
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 vPositionNormal;
void main() 
{
  float a = pow( b + s * abs(dot(vNormal, vPositionNormal)), p );

  // Sample map with UV coordinates. Multiply by uniform to get repeat
  float a2 = texture2D(alphaMap, vUv * repeat).r;

  // Combine both alphas
  float opacity = a * a2;

  gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(vec3(0), glowColor, opacity), 1. );
}
  </script>

  <div id="ThreeJS" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>
```

Comment: Marquizzo - thanks for the detailed solution - unfortunately i can't implement it - i've added your changes to https://codepen.io/royBarak80/pen/zYBWVYG?editors=1011 - and as you can see - i get console errors - which i can't really debug (newbie to custom materials...) - thanks

Comment: @RoyBarOn my mistake, the fragment shader should've read `texture2D().r` instead of just `texture2D()`. I've added an update with the working demo in my answer.

Comment: Marquizzo - thanks!!! - i wonder how can i apply more maps like - bump, colormap - etc .  (i'll update the bounty when it's be available )

Comment: @RoyBarOn Colormap is pretty similar to the way we did `alphaMap` Just sample another `vec3 color = texture2D().rgb` to replace `glowColor`. Bumpmap would be harder because you'd have to displace vertex positions along their normals, so it requires quite a bit of math. I recommend you spend some time with https://thebookofshaders.com/ to get acquainted with shaders, their syntax, and some terminology.